# what object type does self.parent in obj-c return?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c

just curious to know if it would return (id) or (parent class) or something else.

Comment: If you want a better answer than I gave below, give us more than one sentence, or at least rephrase your question to be more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

It would return whatever you define that property to return on that particular object. There is no "parent" property by default on any base object.